# Java get database connection from the server

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc, server

I have one project database connection change from client program to located in Server.

There is Client Program made by java(Awt and Swing) and database connection is exposed as configuration file.

For security purpose we have to hide database connection information.

First I tried encrypt and decrypt in the files id and password information.
However, it is also denied because mainly they don't want to put any database information in the local.

So They want me to setup database connection in the server,

Do you guys have any idea and guide me how to setup that?

I don't want to make big affect,
Just want to get Connection object from server and using that connection in the client side.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. It would be better to provide the data from the server to your clients through services, probably using RMI or a REST architecture.

Comment: or If I run on the server side is it possible to get ResultSet? Because client side has to do something with resultSet information.

Comment: Again: *It would be better to provide the data from the server to your clients through services, probably using RMI or a REST architecture*. Your service can connect to the database, retrieves the necessary data and return it to your client. I recommend you to read on these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You either have to establish the JDBC connection from your client or write a piece of server software that does the connection and gives you the results in some other form, e.g. via REST service.